# Server Time and Client Time -- Difference?

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I have written a code which tells me the time taken by a packet to reach from `server to client` and also total time taken from `client to server to client` again. This is my code.

CLIENT SIDE:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Ping</title>
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(e) {

    var socket = io.connect('http://pingme.jit.su:80/', {secure: false});
    $('#button').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).attr('disabled','disabled');
        var time = (new Date()).getTime();
        socket.emit('ping', time);  
    });
    socket.on('pong', function(data)    {
        var time2 = (new Date()).getTime();
        var lat = time2 - data.server;
        var roundtrip = time2 - data.init;
        var str = '<br><br><strong>From Server</strong>: '+lat+' ms<br><strong>Roundtrip</strong>: '+roundtrip+' ms<br><br>';
        $('#res').prepend(str);
        $('#button').removeAttr('disabled');
    }); 
});
</script>
</head>
<body style="margin:0;">
<input type="button" name="Button" id="button" value="Latency">
<div id="res"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

SERVER SIDE:

```
var app = require('http').createServer(handler)
, io = require('socket.io').listen(app)
, fs = require('fs')
, path = require('path')
, url = require("url")
, querystring = require("querystring");

app.listen(8080);

io.configure('development', function(){
  io.set('transports', ['xhr-polling']);
});

io.configure('production', function(){
  io.set('transports', ['xhr-polling']);
});

var static = require('node-static');
var fileServer = new static.Server('.', { cache: false });

function handler (request, response) {

    var pathname = url.parse(request.url).pathname;
    if(pathname == '/') {
        pathname = '/app.html';
    }   
    request.addListener('end', function () {
        fileServer.serveFile(pathname, 200, {}, request, response, function(err, result)    {
            if(err) {
                console.log(err);
                console.log(err.status);
            }
            else
                console.log(result);                
        });
    });
}

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
    socket.on('ping',function(data) {
        var time = (new Date()).getTime();
        socket.emit('pong', {server:time, init:data});
    });

});
```

The problem while this works well locally showing the following output:

```
From Server: 4 ms
Roundtrip: 11 ms

From Server: 10 ms
Roundtrip: 15 ms
```

I get abnormal results when I run after deploying this on Nodejitsu. It gives me following output:

```
From Server: 2223 ms
Roundtrip: 956 ms

From Server: 2265 ms
Roundtrip: 915 ms
```

How it is this possible that packet takes more time to travel from server than the whole roundtrip? I think it is due to the difference of time between server and client. What do you think it is?

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of reasons why this happens. but if you want to test your programming then you should compare the results to something like traceroute (command on linux).

Things are always going to be WAYYY quicker locally. When you access something outside of your LAN you are going to get all sorts of overheads and latency.

A simple traceroute will probably explain a lot. Also, you can do it from here:

http://www.traceroute.org/

//EDIT//

There are lots of ways you can do this, check this link:

[Latency / Ping test from Browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12035569/latency-ping-test-from-browser)

But the underlying principal, is that you send multiple messages. You can use your first request-response messages to work out the time. I do this with about 1000 clients, what I do is keep track of the **offest** for each one. Once you calculate the offset (i.e. the client is 1 hour ahead of the server), then you can minus it from your latency calculations.  Check out this php function

http://php.net/manual/en/function.timezone-offset-get.php

That should at least help point you in the right direction :) - let me know if you need more help.

Comment: Thanks for the link. But the problem is not the latency. The problem is about the different timestamp at server and client at same instant. Is there some way that I can use a third party universal clock for both client and server??

Comment: When I do work like this, I generally send the client timestamp in the actual message and do the calculation that way. That means that you can work out the offset/difference between the server and client time before you do your calculations. Or you can try and synchronize the clocks first. I don't know of any universal clock, I do know that you can make them synchronise off the same time server though

Comment: Well you don't have control over the server do you? If you do you can sync the unix time with an NTP server by using a command. See this site: http://www.unixsurgeon.com/kb/how-to-sync-server-time-with-ntp-servers.html -   Otherwise, if you don't have access via nodejitsu, then you should send the time stamp in your actual message and work out the time difference.

Comment: I tried to send timestamp with my message to server but the problem is that on my client date and server date are different by a huge margin. Please check http://pingme.jit.su/

Comment: Oh I see, have you got debug bar/firebug or chrome debugger for your browser? if so check out the XHR requests for your site, and compare them to this site: http://www.pingtest.net/ --- I think what you need to do is send more than one message, and work out the average. I will edit my main answer to explain more

Comment: I have one more question -- What if a client intentionally changes the time on his clock? How are we supposed to tackle that. And thanks for the help. Really appreciate it.

Comment: You should be able to detect this from javascript on the client side. Just keep track of the clients clock and if it changes too drastically then you know they have altered it. If you check the client time every 5 seconds, and it has changed by 10 seconds since you last checked it, then you know they have altered their clock by 5 seconds.